# How do I get rid of GNU grub menu at start-up?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10, gnu

I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot mode in my computer.

I formatted the whole partition in which Ubuntu was installed.

Then whenever I start up my PC, I see the GNU grub menu. All I have to do is type in "exit" and then hit enter key.

I am sent back to the Windows 10 startup part.

I don't know Ubuntu kernel language. When for the first time I saw the screen, I  thought typing "exit" will give me a way out of it. And it did. Since then, I have been typing "exit" in the menu and hitting enter every time I open up my PC.

**How to get rid of the menu completely?**

The disk partition in which I installed Ubuntu is completely wiped out.

Comment: It is not the Ubuntu partition you need to wipe out. When ubuntu is installed it installs grub in a smaller, less intrusive partition, generally formatted as ext4 (unless otherwise specified.) You will need to remove all partitions besides the primary Windows NTFS partition, or change boot order from BIOS (if possible)

Comment: I changed the booting option from BIOS menu. It worked.

Comment: That's very good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

As one of my suggestions worked, I will post an answer in case others run into this.

When Ubuntu is installed, it creates a few partitions. One is saved for the grub bootloader, and will be separate from the EXT4 partition is on. This partition should be deleted if you want to completely remove Ubuntu, however as the OP did, if you change boot order to the Windows drive in BIOS, you can bypass having to reformat the disk